# Merge sort time complexity vs my algorithm. Big O

Tags: big-o, analysis, asymptotic-complexity

Here is an algorithm I am trying to analyse (see below). I do not understand why this has a  `O(n)` time complexity when the merge sorts has `O(n logn)`, they both seems to be doing the same thing.

then both have the same j time complexity, if you left j be the row then `2^j X c(n/2^j)` = `cn` and they both have a running time of `log n`, where n is the number of elements.

```
Algorithm: BinarySum(A, i, n)
Input: An array A and integers i and n.
Output: The sum of the n integers in A starting at index i.
if n = 1 then
return A[i]
return BinarySum(A, i, [n/2] ) + BinarySum(A, i + [n/2], [n/2])
```

thanks,
daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are processing for constant time each member of an array. No matter how are you doing this, the resulting complexity will be O(n). By the way, if you use a pen and paper method for a simple example, you'll see that in fact you are calling array's elements exactly in order they appear in the array, which means that this algorithm is equivalent to simple iterative summation.

Formal proof for O(n) complexity follows directly from the [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). Recurrence relation for your algorithm is

```
T(n) = 2 T(n/2)
```

which is covered by case 1 of the theorem. From this complexity is calculated as

```
O(n ^ log_2_(2)) = O(n)
```

As for merge sort, its recurrence relation is

```
T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(n)
```

which is a totally different story - case 2 of the Master theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence formula for your algorithm is;

```
 2T(n/2) = O(n)
```

whereas the recurrence formula for the merge sort is;

```
 2T(n/2) + O(n) = O(n log n)
```

as there are two recursive calls + a call to a merge function which takes O(n). Your function just makes two recursive calls, check out the break down;

http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~luebke/cs332.fall00/lecture3/sld004.htm

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following pseudo code:

```
 1    MergeSort(a, p, r)
 2      if  P<r                                // check for base case
 3      then q = FLOOR p+r/2                   // Divide
 4      MergeSort(a, p, q)                     // conquer
 5      MergeSort(a, q+1, r)                   // conquer
 6      Merge(a, p, q, r)                      // Merge
```

Now the complexity will be as follows:

for

Line 3 :- O(1) since it takes constant time.

Line 4 :- T(n/2) because it operates on the half of elements.

Line 5 :- T(n/2) because it operates on the half of elements.

Line 6 :- T(n)   because it operates on the all the elements

Now using the recurrence relation as mentioned by @Lunar we can state that the time complexity is equivalent to :- O(nlgn)